# Unable to boot in recovery mode - dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, nvidia, recovery-mode, tpm

I dual booted Ubuntu 18.04 with Windows 10 on my laptop. It was working fine until one day it just started showing this error:

```
Error connecting to tpm chip
```

I have tried following some fix suggestions I found online, like turning on the TPM chip from the BIOS, but there is no TPM chip option available in the BIOS.

I am trying to boot in recovery mode so that I can reinstall/update the graphics card drivers, but I am getting the following error (refer to the pictures attached):

**GRUB Option**

[image: GRUB Option]

**Error screen**

[image: Error screen]

Following are my laptop specs:

- ASUS ROG
- Intel core i7
- NVIDIA GTX 1660
- 16gb RAM

Comment: apologies for that. I have edited the question. It is ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: I recently did a contract using UEFI boot, encrypted drives and uses TPM's so this screen is very familiar to me.

In effect the initramfs has failed to mount your drive and thus is can't find a volume with the UUID indicated.

I don't see anything there that indicates a TPM error..

So is your drive encrypted and how was it unlocked at boot time?

Comment: If I try to boot it in normal mode, it shows the "Error connecting to TPM chip" error. I was advised to boot it in safe graphics mode. I tried doing that and it ended up showing this screen.

Comment: Was the machine installed with secure boot?

Comment: I disabled the secure boot.

Comment: OK so its possible that kernel modules were upgraded or removed and that invalidated the boot..   You'll need a rescue disk to boot from.

Comment: https://ostechnix.com/how-to-fix-busybox-initramfs-error-on-ubuntu/

Comment: If you encrypted the drive and can remember the password I can tell you how todo that from the initramfs prompt..

Comment: Try the rescue and fsck route first..